# Download a file of different file types which was sent by flask

Tags: javascript

This is what I get by Flask:

```
@app.route('/api/downloads/', methods=['POST'])
def download_file():

    uploads = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']

    try:
        response = request.get_json()
        filename = response["filename"]
        return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, path=filename, as_attachment=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {}, 404
```

This is my JavaScript, I got this snippet from here:

```
function downloadStuff (data) {

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    var binaryData = [];
    binaryData.push(data);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"})) <- ?
    link.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

}
```

On `const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"}))` I define the type, like here: "zip".

How can I be independent on the file type specification since I want to be able to download different file types and not only "zip"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pass second argument as a type and use it in your function like this. (Note: make zip bydefault if you don't pass any type it takes zip)

```
function downloadStuff (data, type = 'zip') {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  var binaryData = [];
  binaryData.push(data);
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, 
   {type:`application/${type}`})) <- ?
  link.href = url;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```